# store name and value of textbox to database using php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to save name and value of textbox to database.

i have the textbox with name attribute  text1,text2,text3  and value is those user enter in each textbox.

```
 <form action='save.php' method='post' name='form1'>
<label>Text1</label> <input type="text" name="Text1"  />

<label>Text2</label> <input type="text" name="Text2"  />

<label>Text3</label> <input type="text" name="Text3"  />
<input type="submit" name="save"  value="save" /> 
</form>


i have database table like this,
ID is Auto increment.  

ID     name     value
1      text1    xyz
2      text2    abc
2      text3    pqr
```

Need some help for  start up.

How can i do this using php.can i need to use javscript for this.

please suggest anything so i can start with this.

if have any link those helful to me to achive my goal please share.

Comment: what you know about db in general, any comamnds like insert or update at all?

Comment: @Ark:i am aware of mysql all commands.

Comment: refer w3schools.com PHP tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are starting up, do this :

Change your form tag to

```
      <form action='save.php' method='post' name='form1'>
```

Create a new file save.php which is same as in the form's action attribute.

Now add this is save.php

```
      $text1=$_POST['Text1'];
      $text2=$_POST['Text2'];
      $text3=$_POST['Text3'];
```

create a database connection with mysql followed by this:

```
      $sql=mysql_query('insert into tablename(name, value)values($text1,$text2)');
```

this is just an idea. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can learn PHP easily and step by step at w3schools.com

Here is the link: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your form tag to:

```
<form method="post" action="yourphppage.php">
```